# Intersection of pentagons

Tags: geometry

> Are there $n$ convex pentagons on the plane such that the intersection of any two of them is a heptagon, for any $n$?

If we want two pentagons, this is possible. Suppose the first pentagon is $ABCDE$ and the second pentagon $FGHIJ$. We let segment $AE$ intersect $FG$, $BC$ intersect $GH$, and $CD$ and $DE$ intersect $IJ$. For three pengatons it is harder to draw a picture and keep track of the intersections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Pentagons]

Worth a thousand words, they say.